# Regular Expression relace Myname _Mysurname with "" in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression which replaces a string like this

```
"Myname _MySurename"  with "Myname"
```

that means i just need Myname, so _MySurename should be cut.

i tryed something like "/_*/" but that replaces just the _ (underscore) 
how can i do that in PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it is obvious you
know **where** your string has to
be **splitted**.
Therefore: better not use regex substitution,
but use regex split:

```
preg_split('/\s*_/', $text)
```

This returns the list of splitted entries,
get the first one e.g. by:

```
...
$names = 'Myname_MySurename'; #  'Myname _MySurename';
# print first element of splitted array
$firstname = array_shift( preg_split('/\s*_/', $names) );
...
```

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `underscore` and the following `word` as:

```
$str = preg_replace('/_\w+/','',$str);
```

Looks like you also have a space after the name. So you can use:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s*_\w+/','',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/\s_.+$/
```

"Replace a whitespace (the space) followed by an underscore and a number of characters". The `$` makes sure that this is matched on the end of the string.

This is untested, but it should work.